# Making a sticky form in PHP with HTML

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to generate a sticky form in PHP and it's not working. The code that I have is:

```
<html>
    <h1>Customer Feedback</h1>
    <p1>Please tell us what you think</p1><br><br>
    <form method='POST' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>' >
        <p1>Your name:</p1><br>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" value="<?php echo $fullname; ?>"><br><br>
        <p1>Your email address:</p1><br>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="php echo $email;"><br><br>
        <p1>Your feedback:</p1><br>
        <textarea rows="5"  cols="50" name="feedback"><?php echo $text;?>  </textarea><br><br>
        <input type="submit" Value="Send Feedback"><br><br>
        <?php
            error_reporting(E_ALL);


            $name = $_POST['fullname'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $feed = $_POST['feedback'];

            if (empty($name)) 
            {
                echo "Please enter your name.";
            }
            if (empty($email)) 
            {
                echo "Please enter your email and feedback.";
            }
            if (empty($feed))
            {
                echo "Please enter feedback.";
            }
            if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($feed))
            {
                echo "You have inserted the correct data";
            }
        ?>
    </form>
</html>
```

When I run the code, the email text box is already full with `php echo $email;` and it's not wanting to keep the text boxes full when I'm pressing the Send Feedback button.

**Edit**
I've put the tags round the input value on the email line and the form carries on emptying when I press the 'Submit Feedback' button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this if you want to display data after submitting the form   :

```
<?php
$fullname = "";
$email = "";
$text = "";
if(isset($_POST['fullname']) && $_POST['fullname'] != "") {
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
}
if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != "") {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}
if(isset($_POST['feedback']) && $_POST['feedback'] != "") {
    $text= $_POST['feedback'];
}
?>
<html>
    <h1>Customer Feedback</h1>
    <p1>Please tell us what you think</p1><br><br>
    <form method='POST' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>' >
        <p1>Your name:</p1><br>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" value="<?php echo $fullname; ?>"><br><br>
        <p1>Your email address:</p1><br>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"><br><br>
        <p1>Your feedback:</p1><br>
        <textarea rows="5"  cols="50" name="feedback"><?php echo $text;?>  </textarea><br><br>
        <input type="submit" Value="Send Feedback"><br><br>
        <?php
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            //your rest of PHP code
        ?>
    </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"><br><br>
```

you don't have php tags on this input value

Comment: Thanks I've editted it with the php tags round the input value :) but the data still doesn't want to stay in the form when I press the submit button

Comment: it's going to refresh the page you have to use `javascript` if you dont want to reload the page when you submit your form.

Comment: @MattMagallo Please see my answer.OP wants this. But still you got my +1 for that error.